# sum of weigted multiplicative function

Tags: number-theory

Let $f$ is mulitplicative function, and $N$ is given integer,

then,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{l=1}^{n} \lfloor \frac{n}{l} \rfloor f(l) $$

How compute this nicely?

Is there no way to get this with O(N) if $f$ is preprocessed?

Comment: If $f(\cdot)$ is large, how would you hope for the sum to be $O(N)$? For example, $f(n) = n$ is multiplicative and for this choice of $f$ your sum certainly won't be $O(N)$

Comment: @syxiao You're wrong, sorry! It's always possible to get rid of the double summation, no matter what shape $f$ has, that would get it down to $O(N)$ above the cost of evaluation of $f$. Further simplifications depend on $f$, naturally. In the (admittedly trivial) case $f(n)=n$ you propose, the whole sum can be computed in $O(N^{1/2})$ integer operations.

Comment: I don’t think we are saying the same thing. I thought the question is asking for a bound of $O(N)$ for double sum, which cannot hold for $f(n) = n$. Indeed, the double sum is bounded from below by $\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$, which when $f(n) = n$ is equal to $N(N +1)/2$

Comment: @Professor Vector   Can you help me little more? I can't get rid of double summation. How can i get it down?

Comment: @syxiao if f equals n, then using prefix sum we can calculate it for O(n). futhermore, by harmonic lemma, for O(sqrt N)

Comment: @syxiao  That was a misunderstanding, then: the OP is not trying to bound the sum itself, but the time-complexity to compute it. Of course, the question could have been formulated a bit more clearly (hint!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a double sum, which (if implemented naively) would require $O(N^2)$ integer operations, additionally to the cost of computing the $f$-values. A standard technique in such cases is to change the order of summation. The sum is over all pairs $(n,l)$ satisfying $1\le l\le n\le N$, so we can sum over $n$, first:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{l=1}^{n} \lfloor n/l \rfloor f(l)=\sum^N_{l=1}f(l)\sum^N_{n=l}\lfloor n/l \rfloor.$$
Now $\lfloor n/l \rfloor$ is constant between consecutive multiples of $l$, so we have some blocks of $l$ equal values plus some rest of a period where $\lfloor n/l \rfloor=\lfloor N/l \rfloor$, meaning
$$s(N,l)=\sum^N_{n=l}\lfloor n/l \rfloor=l\,\frac{\lfloor N/l \rfloor(\lfloor N/l \rfloor-1)}2+(N \bmod l+1)\,\lfloor N/l \rfloor.$$ Using $N \bmod l=N-l\,\lfloor N/l \rfloor$, we can write this as $$s(N,l)=(N+1)\,\lfloor N/l \rfloor-l\,\frac{\lfloor N/l \rfloor(\lfloor N/l \rfloor+1)}2.$$ Depending on the shape of $f$, the resulting sum $$\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{l=1}^{n} \lfloor n/l \rfloor f(l)=\sum^N_{l=1}f(l)\,s(N,l)$$ can often be computed still more efficiently, using the fact that $\lfloor N/l \rfloor$ takes only $O(N^{1/2})$ different values.

Comment: wow i reallllly appreciate!!!

Comment: changing order of double summation is difficult for me, i had never thought about that